# How set my timezone correctly to save a record correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, timezone

In my rails application I'm getting data and saving it by its date for all the records that has the today's date for a later call.

The problem is the data comes in this format **"8:05 PM ET"**

When I parse it to get it in the date format I get this:

```
"Mon, 24 Aug 2015 20:05:00 EDT -04:00"
```

,which is the right date. The thing is when I save it in the database is saved as

```
"2015-08-25 00:05:00 UTC"
```

When I request to the db give me all the data from today it doesn't retrieve this record because the date says that record is 25 "tomorrow"** and not **24 "today".

How can I save that record in my database as 
**today "24"** and not as
**tomorrow "25"**?

My configuration:

application.rb

```
class Application < Rails::Application
    Dir["#{Rails.root}/lib/**/**/*.rb"].each { |f| require f }
    config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'.freeze
    config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
end
```

and before save it:

```
string = '7:05 PM ET'
datetime = DateTime.now
Time.use_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)') do
      datetime = Time.zone.parse(string)
 end
baz.create(time: datetime, foo: 'bar')
```

when i try to acces it

```
baz.where(time:Date.today.to_time.beginning_of_day..Date.today.to_time.end_of_day)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your database, dates are saved in `UTC`.

But, if you want to retrieve the dates in your own timezone format, you can specify your timezone in the `config/application.rb` filelike this:

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'.freeze
```

Then, you can do:

```
time_now =  DateTime.now
time_now_in_my_zone = time_now.in_time_zone(Rails.application.config.time_zone).to_datetime
```

See [ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html)

To keep things consistent and saving time in local timezone to database, this has to be set in `application.rb`

```
 config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

Default timezone is `:utc`.

See [Configuring Active Record](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-active-record) for more options.

So, you can use `config.active_record.default_timezone = :local` setting to save the date in your local format and retrieve it in your format too, and keep things consistent. I think, this answers your question. Let me know if not!

#### Update

Change:

```
Time.use_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)') do
      datetime = Time.zone.parse(string)
 end
```

to:

```
datetime = Time.now.in_time_zone(Rails.application.config.time_zone).to_datetime
    baz.create(time: datetime, foo: 'bar')
```

Comment: I still having the same problem  when i request in active record:  `{where  time:Date.today.to_time.beginning_of_day..Date.today.to_time.end_of_day}` does not bring me all the records because some of them are from 25 no 24, thats in the request but if i try to access the property i get the right date but i need it right when i request it. example if i say `person.time` i get **"Mon, 24 Aug 2015 22:00:00 EDT -04:00"** is right but in the request above i dont get that record because in database is 25.

Comment: Did you add ` config.active_record.default_timezone = :local` to your application.rb file?

Comment: Yes i did and still behaving like that.

Comment: To be consistent, you can save the date with local timezone config in the database, then when you will retrieve, it will get the correct date.

Comment: can you show your application.rb file? and where are you trying to write this query and where are you saving into teh database?

Comment: If you can save the date in EDT format in the database, then you will be able to retrieve it in the EDT format too. Did you delete your previous data when they had the UTC dates?

Comment: Look at my updated answer. Try that to save the date in tour time_zone format specified in the application.rb

Comment: the thing is I don't want the time of now, I going to get different times of today like "8:05 PM ET"  or "10:05 PM ET" but doesn't mean that i have that time when I save it

Comment: The way you re currently saving your dates is that correct? Did you check the time_zone in the database after saving? If its saved in the correct zone, then you should get that zone when you retrieve unless ActiveRecord overrides that.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider studying a little more about [time zones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X1DkiuaFCuA).

in your case `Mon, 24 Aug 2015 20:05:00 EDT -04:00` is the same date as `2015-08-25 00:05:00 UTC`

UTC means the timezone +00:00

Comment: but why when im trying to retrieve that data of "today" in rails it doesn't appear that record but if i put tomorrow it does appear. how i should request that.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter way to achieve that:

1. Set `config.time_zone` in your `application.rb` file.
2. Use `Time.zone.now` to save your records.

**Example:**
Setting *'Buenos Aires'* timezone in a Rails application.rb file.

```
# Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
config.time_zone = 'Buenos Aires'
```

Then you can use this to store the properly Time:
`Time.zone.now # => Mon, 24 Aug 2015 13:06:21 ART -03:00`

If you want to know what *time_zone* do you need, you can run this: `rake time:zones:all`

Hope this help :)